# Doctrine setParameter and Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After many tries, I think I finally know the documentation by heart.
Then, I need your help .. I don't understand why Doctrine show me this error :

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens

Here is my code :

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('m')
   ->from('Entities\Marque', 'm')
   ->leftJoin('m.magasin', 'ma')
   ->where('m.nom = :marque AND ma.nom LIKE :magasin')
   ->setParameter('marque', $marque)
   ->setParameter('magasin', '%'.$matchesNumber[1].'%');
$results = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Are you maybe calling $db->where at a later point? This would overwrite the existing where-statement.

Comment: No, it's the only one use of where statement.

Comment: Are `$marque` and `$matchesNumber[1]` not null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm so sorry .. I just found my error .. Later, like more later in my code .. I type a new query with my old "$qb" ..
I'm such a noob !

Answer (score 12):

This also happens if you accidentally use more than one `where()`, which happened to me once.

```
$em    = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('AppBundle:SomeEntity', 's')
    ->select('s')
    ->where('s.foo = :foo')
    ->where('s.bar = :bar') // <- HERE
    ->setParameter('foo', 'Foo Value')
    ->setParameter('bar', 'Bar Value');
```

Should be:

```
$em    = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('AppBundle:SomeEntity', 's')
    ->select('s')
    ->where('s.foo = :foo')
    ->andWhere('s.bar = :bar') // <- CHANGE TO andWhere()
    ->setParameter('foo', 'Foo Value')
    ->setParameter('bar', 'Bar Value');
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 8):

I presume ->setParameter overrides the previous one.

For multiple Parameters use:

```
->setParameters(['key1' => $value1, 'key2' => $value2])
```

See Doctrine Upgrade:

> From now on, parameters in queries is an ArrayCollection instead of a simple array. This >affects heavily the usage of setParameters(), because it will not append anymore parameters >to query, but will actually override the already defined ones. Whenever you are retrieving a >parameter (ie. $query->getParameter(1))

[Doctrine Upgrade Description](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/UPGRADE.md)

Maybe that also applies to setParameter?

Comment: I had already try `->setParameters(['marque' => $marque, 'magasin' => '%'.$matchesNumber[1].'%']);` But no changes ..

Answer (score 4):

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$parameters = array('marque'=>$marque, 'magasin'=>'%'.$matchesNumber[1].'%');
$qb->select('m')
   ->from('Entities\Marque', 'm')
   ->leftJoin('m.magasin', 'ma')
   ->where('m.nom = :marque')
   ->andWhere('ma.nom LIKE :magasin')
   ->setParameters($parameters);

$results = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```